# Django: displaying a foreign key of a model in template

Tags: python, html, django

this is a rather basic question (I'm new to Django) i'm having trouble displaying a foreign key in the template.
i have this model which has 'employer' as a ManyToManyField in the Job model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Employer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    business = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")
    team = models.IntegerField()
    about = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    country =  models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")


class Job(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    specialism = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    employer = models.ManyToManyField(Employer)
```

I try to get all jobs that contains "Computers" as specialism:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Job, Employer

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html')

def post_list(request):

    jobs = Job.objects.all().filter(specialism="Computers")
    return render(request, 'wall.html',{'jobs':jobs})
```

And for every job i wanna display the employer name in the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>WALL</h1></center>
{% block content %}
{{jobs.count}}
{% for job in jobs %}
    <h2>specialism :{{job.specialism}} employer: {{job.employer.name}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I get None as a value for job.employer.name. so how can i display the name of the employer for every job?

Answer (score 2):

That is because you didn't use foriegn key but many to many field

Try this if a job has only one employer

```
employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer)
```

Comment: What's the difference may i ask?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ForeignKey` instead of `ManyToManyField`

Change `Job` model to following

```
class Job(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    specialism = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer)
```

---

**Explanation**

Consider following model

```
class Company(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class AppliancePart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class Appliance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
```

In the above model an `AppliancePart` can belong to only one `Company` but one `Company` can manufacture more than one `AppliancePart`. Where as when we are talking about `Appliance`, an `Appliance` can be made of parts manufactured by one or more than one `Company`, hence the relationship is 
`many appliances <--> many companies`

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25389754/3442707) for more information