# Django select from table with multiple column values "or"

Tags: python, django

I have a Books table where I want to retrieve all records based on different column values

e.g

```
Select * from Books where bookid = 2 || bookid = 3 || bookid = 4;
```

The book ids I get is from a Rent table:

```
    rents =Rents.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

So I have a queryset of rents object that contains a property bookid.

How do I get Books based on all the values of the rents?

Answer (score 0):

[Whats the difference between a OneToOne, ManyToMany, and a ForeignKey Field in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386119/whats-the-difference-between-a-onetoone-manytomany-and-a-foreignkey-field-in-d/25389754#25389754)

Check this out. It also tells you aboue how Django let you view relationships in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Q` objects for doing `or` or `and` operations. Here is the example:

```py
from django.db.models import Q    # import Q object for queryset

rents = Rents.objects.filter(Q(bookid__exact=2) | Q(bookid__exact=3) | Q(bookid__exact=4), user=request.user)
```

`rents` will have objects with user logged user having book_id of 2 or 3 or 4. I don't know how your models are structured, but this is one of the way to do so.

Here is the reference from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

**EDIT**

**Q** object is provided, it must precede the definition of any keyword argument. But, I was just doing exact opposite.